# why 'pushb $12' errors in gas?

Tags: x86-64, gnu-assembler

Why the following code illegal in gas?

```
# cat -n gas.asm
1
2  .code64
3  pushb $12
4
# as gas.asm
gas.asm: Assembler messages:
gas.asm:3: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `push'
```

Isn't it matchs:

```
| Opcode* | Instruction | Op/En | 64-Bit Mode | Compat/Leg Mode | Description |
|      6A | PUSH imm8   | C     | Valid       | Valid           | Push imm8.  |
```

But, the following code works in NASM.

```
bits 64
push byte 12
```

Why gas get that error on X86-64 platform?

Thanks!

Comment: Pushing a single byte would leave the stack unaligned. BAD(tm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this thread](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Assembler/comp.lang.asm.x86/2006-03/msg00253.html).

Quote:

> I think what you are refering to is '0x6A PUSH imm8'. **This does not push a
>   byte onto the stack**.  It pushes a byte value, encoded as part of the
>   instruction, as either a word (16-bits) or the CPU size [longword (32-bits)
>   for 32-bit CPUs and quadword (64-bits) for 64-bit CPUs] depending on the
>   stack size for the current CPU mode and size override prefixes.

In short, this is in effect a `pushw`. `gas` make this fact explicit and force you to use `pushw $12`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I debugged the code NASM generated, It's works as you said.